# windows10でlinuxの仮想マシンからhttpsのサイトにwgetを実行して、443 failed: Host is unreachable. と出ています。

Tags: linux, windows, ssl, wget

windows10でlinuxのvirutual-box仮想マシンからhttpsのサイトからコマンドをダウンロードするためにwgetを実行して、
443 failed: Host is unreachable.
となってしまいます。

情報提供いただけますと幸いです。

以下を確認しています。
・Wget　のバージョンは 1.20.3
・--no-check-certificateオプションを指定しても同じ結果になる
・ldd /usr/bin/wgetでlibssl.soが表示されている

Comment: windows10の仮想マシンはWSL,WSL2,hyper-v,vmware,virutual-boxなどがあり、それぞれ対応が違いますので、何を使っているか書いてください。

Comment: `http://` のサイトに対しては正常に実行できるのでしょうか？

Comment: "Host is unreachable" と表示されているという事で routing の問題かな、とも思いますが、wget コマンドには "--debug" オプションがありますので、それを付けて実行してみるともう少し詳しい状況が判るかもしれません。